# Service wont initialize when exported to seperate class

Tags: flutter, dart

Whenever I am trying to launch background service from a seperate class then it doesn't work at all, nothing happens. However when I include all the methods under `void main()` in `main.dart` file and in main use `await initializeService();` then it works. Why I can't launch this from an external class that I have created? I don't want to keep all the methods in the main file because it's getting messy. Am I doing something wrong? I am using this library
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await BackgroundService().initializeService();
  child: const MyApp()));
}
```

```dart
class BackgroundService {

  Future<void> initializeService() async {
    final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
    await service.configure(
      androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
        // this will executed when app is in foreground or background in separated isolate
        onStart: onStart,

        // auto start service
        autoStart: true,
        isForegroundMode: true,
      ),
      iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
        // auto start service
        autoStart: true,

        // this will executed when app is in foreground in separated isolate
        onForeground: onStart,

        // you have to enable background fetch capability on xcode project
        onBackground: onIosBackground,
      ),
    );
  }

// to ensure this executed
// run app from xcode, then from xcode menu, select Simulate Background Fetch
  void onIosBackground() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    print('FLUTTER BACKGROUND FETCH');
  }

  void onStart() {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
    service.onDataReceived.listen((event) {
      if (event!["action"] == "setAsForeground") {
        service.setForegroundMode(true);
        return;
      }

      if (event["action"] == "setAsBackground") {
        service.setForegroundMode(false);
      }

      if (event["action"] == "stopService") {
        service.stopBackgroundService();
      }
    });

    // bring to foreground
    service.setForegroundMode(true);
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) async {
      if (!(await service.isServiceRunning())) timer.cancel();
      service.setNotificationInfo(
        title: "My App Service",
        content: "Updated at ${DateTime.now()}",
      );

      print("Hello");
      service.sendData(
        {
          "current_date": DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
          // "device": device,
        },
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: you can make your functions onStart,onIosBackground,initializeService as static and then use it like this in main await BackgroundService.initializeService() i have tested it and it worked

Comment: @mohityadav still doesn't seem to work for me. Now it started, but the onStart method doesn't start at all, it just says `Background service - preparing` in the notification screen.

Comment: `Dart Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: No top-level getter 'onStart' declared`

Comment: @mohityadav yeah I made them all static. When I wrap the methods in a class then it doesn't work, but without class it doesn't, completely don't understand this.

Comment: @mohityadav I know it will work without the class, I've stated that in my question, but I need to get this to work with seperate class

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/issues/159